# Why is clang defining NULL as __null?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, clang++, llvm-clang

I have a .cpp file which has usage of **NULL** at several places. When I try to compile this cpp file for Android/x86 platform using clang++ on Windows machine + standalone tool chain, I am running into "expected expression" error at the places where **NULL** is used. I find the definition of **NULL** in stddef.h of clang headers provided by Android NDK as below.

```
#if defined(__need_NULL)
#undef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#  if !defined(__MINGW32__) && !defined(_MSC_VER)
#    define NULL __null
#  else
#    define NULL 0
#  endif
#else
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
#endif
```

As far as I know, `__null` is specific to GNU compiler. In my case both _MSC_VER and  `__MINGW32__` are undefined because I am compiling for Android platform using clang++ and standalone tool chain. So it is hitting into `define NULL __null`. Since clang++ has no clue of what `__null` is, it is resulting into "expected expression" error.

My question is, why is clang using macros(like `__null`) provided by GNU compiler? Or am I missing something here?

Could somebody please help me understand. Thanks

Comment: Just use `nullptr` already..

Comment: What standalone toolchain? Also you can try adding `-D__MINGW32__` and see if it works..

Comment: Yes, make sure nobody redefines `__null`

Answer (score 1):

> Why is clang defining NULL as __null?

`__null` is superior to `0`, because former is only a null pointer constant, while the latter is also an integer constant. This difference is significant in case of overload resolution and type deduction:

```
void foo(int);
void foo(void*);

foo(0);       // calls foo(int)
foo(__null);  // call is ambiguous, program is ill-formed
foo(NULL);    // could have either behaviour
              //  call to foo(int) would be undesirable
foo(nullptr); // calls foo(void*)
```

The reason is same or similar as why `nullptr` was introduced to the language in C++11.

Another reason to do so is that clang strives to be closely compatible with GCC.

> Since clang++ has no clue of what __null is

clang++ [appears](https://godbolt.org/z/qDpBHs) to know what `__null` is.

Comment: But isn't __null gnu specific? why is it used in clang code? How will clang get to know about gnu compiler's specific macros?

Comment: @Pendyala Clang supports many GNU extensions. Including this one, apparently: https://godbolt.org/z/fsFNjP

Comment: please check https://godbolt.org/z/GihtJE. It seems __null is not supported by clang.

Comment: @Pendyala Your example doesn't compile in GCC either: https://godbolt.org/z/LO0URg

Comment: @Pendyata:  To declare an abstract virtual method, you must use "= 0".  You're not assigning a pointer.  "= NULL" is incorrect C++, regardless of the compiler, and regardless of whether it happens to work on some compilers.